# /bin/sh: node: command not found in amazon ec2 when running through the exec("node --version")

Tags: node.js, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, command-line-interface

I have my project uploaded on amazon ec2 which uses the exec() function to run command line commands, it works well on my device if I run exec("node --version") through node js but when I uploaded the project to the cloud I installed node and npm and all packages project was running smoothly.
But when it came to running the exec("node --version") it is giving me this error

[image: erorr bin/sh command not found]

Strange thing is that when I run the command manually

[image]

In my windows, all commands were running perfectly.

Is it searching the bin/sh directory for node sh?

CODE:

```
exec('node --version', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
      console.log("::::::::::::"+stdout);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node is not in the system path of the `sh` shell environment. Try to add the path, or call the executable with the full path.

Comment: i got the ts-node path using which node `~/.nvm/versions/node/v17.4.0/bin/ts-node` and i verified it by running it on CLI and it worked.
now when i ran this using ` exec('~/.nvm/versions/node/v17.4.0/bin/ts-node --version')
it is giving me error /usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory

Comment: @AmirAlam In both cases run command `echo $PATH` (on server)